# how to replace substring in a file according to specific pattern without programming

Tags: vim, sed, awk

suppose I have a file:

its format should be :
number, string1 , [string2] ,....

here string1 should not contain ',' ,because we use ',' to separate each column
but due to some reason ,string1 now contain some ',' inside it, 
so we need to replace it with other symbol ,such as '-'

```
1,aaa,bbb,ccc,[x,y,z],eee,fff,ggg
2,q,w,[x],f,g
3,z,[y],g,h
4,zzz,xxx,ccc,vvv,[z],g,h
....
```

should be revised to :

```
1,aaa-bbb-ccc,[x,y,z],eee,fff,ggg
2,q-w,[x],f,g
3,z,[y],g,h
4,zzz-xxx-ccc-vvv,[z],g,h
....
```

what's the best way to do it without programming , I mean we just use awk,sed,vim rather than shell programming,python,c++,etc

Thanks

Comment: Is the second field in the end result always surrounded by square brackets? What's wrong with using Python or Perl?

Comment: I suspect that the hope is there will be a one-liner that works inside vim or through a simple pipe that can be used from within the editor.

Comment: I guess you mean the third field, yes, the third field always surrounded by square brackets. python or perl is ok,but I prefer to use  command line instructions to accomplish it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {two=$0;sub($1 FS,"",two);sub(/,[[].*/,"",two);gsub(/,/,"-",two); rest=$0;sub(/^[^[]*/,"",rest); print $1,two,rest}' input.txt 
1,aaa-bbb-ccc,[x,y,z],eee,fff,ggg
2,q-w,[x],f,g
3,z,[y],g,h
4,zzz-xxx-ccc-vvv,[z],g,h
$
```

Let's break out the awk script for easier commenting.

```
$ awk -F, '
  BEGIN { OFS=FS }
  {
    two=$0;                # Second field is based on the line...
    sub($1 FS,"",two);     # Remove the first field,
    sub(/,[[].*/,"",two);  # Remove everything from the [ onwards,
    gsub(/,/,"-",two);     # Replace commas in whatever remains.

    rest=$0;               # Last part of the line, after "two"
    sub(/^[^[]*/,"",rest); # Strip everything up to the [

    print $1,two,rest;     # Print it.
  }
' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

a little long, but you can use `sed` like this:

```
sed ':loop; s/\([0-9]\+,.*\)\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)\(.*,\[\)/\1\2-\3\4/; t loop' \
     input_file
```

slightly shorter one:

```
sed ':loop; s/\([0-9]*,[^\[,]*\),\([^\[,]*,\[\)/\1-\2/; t loop' input_file
```

description for the second one:

```
loop while there are matches                   # :loop;
  1) find numbers followed by a comma,         #   \([0-9]*,
       followed by anything not comma or '[',  #   [^\[,]*\)
  2) find comma                                #   ,
  3) find anything not ',' or '['              #   \([^\[,]*
  4) followed by a ',' and '['                 #   ,\[\)/
  5) replace the whole thing with
       match of step 1 and '-' and matches 
       from steps 3-4                          #   /\1-\2/;
end loop

                                   # t loop
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it under mac,but unfortunately, it seems it is not work for me, the output remains the same, sed ':loop; s/\([0-9]*,[^\[,]*\),\([^\[,]*,\[\)/\1-\2/; t loop' aaa.txt .

Comment: @camino - the sed script you listed in your comment is *not* the same as the "shorter one" that perreal posted in this answer.  The backslashes in front of the brackets are important.  That said ... it doesn't work for me either.  :-/  Perhaps it requires GNU sed, though at first glance I can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e 's/,\[/\n&/;h;s/\n.*//;s/,/-/2g;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```